# XSD allow double by half

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes, double, complextype

I'd like to have a restriction to `xsd:complexType` what would contains only values between `0.5` to `20`, both included, with step by `0.5`. It means numbers:

```
0.5    1   1.5   2   2.5   3   3.5  .. up to 20
```

My code is here:

```
<xsd:complexType name="skillType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="skillHalfDoubleType">
            <xsd:attribute name="special">
                <!-- Irrelevant attribute -->
            </xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="skillHalfDoubleType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
         <!-- What more? -->
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

---

It's possible to do it with regex applied on `xsd:string`, however I look for the solution with restricting `xsd:double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XML Schema 1.1 you can write an assertion that restricts the values

```
<xs:simpleType name="skillHalfDoubleType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
        <xs:assertion test="$value = (for $d in 1 to 40 return 0.5 * $d)"></xs:assertion>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Or you could have a minInclusive facet, a maxInclusive facet, and the assertion facet `round($value*2) = $value*2` to test that it's a multiple of 0.5.

Answer (score 3):

One simple (though verbose) solution would be to use an enumeration:

```
<xs:enumerationvalue="0.5"/>
<xs:enumerationvalue="1"/>
<xs:enumerationvalue="1.5"/>
...
```

A more elegant solution would be to use a pattern combined with min and maxInclusive :

```
<xs:minInclusivevalue="0"/>
<xs:maxInclusivevalue="20"/>
<xs:pattern value="([1-9]?[0-9])|([1-9]?[0-9].5)"/>
```

The latter allows easier range adaptions, but may confuse some schema-aware suggestion providers, as pointed out by C. M. Sperberg-McQueen.

Comment: Yes, a quite straighforward way. It's usable until I change my mind and require from `0.5` to `100`. However +1 for a solution :)

Comment: Yes, a pattern will work, too, although schema-aware software that generates suggestions will often find patterns harder to deal with than enumerations.  If the pattern is made less restrictive (e.g. `.*(\.[05]0*`), you can avoid saying more than was intended; the OP did not mention any requirement to forbid leading signs or leading and trailing zeroes.  It also makes it easier to change the range.